# How to change font size of Y axis scales when using doubleYScale from latticeExtra in R

Tags: r, lattice

I want to change font size of Y axis scales (not the labels, but the numbers next to the ticks) when using doubleYScale. I have managed to change the font size of X axes, both the X and Y axes labels, but am struggling with Y axis font size.

```
foo <- list(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))
obj1 <- xyplot(y ~ x, foo, type = "l", scales = list(y = list(cex=2)))
obj2 <- xyplot(y ^ 2 ~ x, foo, type = "l", scales = list(y = list(cex = 2)))

doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.axis = TRUE)
```

Here the cex has no effect on font size of the y axis scale.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, maybe the easiest is to do:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
trellis.par.set(axis.text=list(cex=2))
doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.axis = TRUE)
```

[image]

If you don't want to change the default, then try this:

```
update(doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.axis = TRUE),
par.settings =list(axis.text=list(cex=2)))
```

My settings:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] latticeExtra_0.6-28 RColorBrewer_1.1-2  lattice_0.20-38    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1    grid_3.6.1
```

Comment: Thanks, the trellis.par works, but for some reason the second solution par.settings does not work. And am curious about this, why would I not want to change the default?

Comment: Weird.. You can see my settings above, maybe it's a matter of package versions. There's no issue, just that you have to change the default settings back for the next plot?